# Power steering tightening up

Tags: toyota, camry, power-steering

Why is My 2000 Toyota Camry's steering is tightening, fluid is full and pump not making sounds.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! More than likely, the belt is slipping.